# Encrypt and Decrypt an ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, encryption, file-io, aes

I need to store an array list of strings in a file by encrypting it. And then I decrypt the file content and restore them to a array list. But when i decrypt the content, blocks of 'Null' are there inside the content. With no 'Null' blocks, rest of the text are the same as i encoded.

```
public static void encryptFile(List<String> moduleList, File fileOut) {
    try {
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileOut);
        out = new CipherOutputStream(out, encryptCipher);
        StringBuilder moduleSet = new StringBuilder();
        for (String module : moduleList) {
            moduleSet.append(module + "#");
        }
        out.write(moduleSet.toString().getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (java.io.IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}

public static List<String> decryptFile(File fileIn) {
    List<String> moduleList = new ArrayList<String>();
    byte[] buf = new byte[16];

    try {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(fileIn);
        in = new CipherInputStream(in, decryptCipher);

        int numRead = 0;
        int counter = 0;
        StringBuilder moduleSet = new StringBuilder();
        while ((numRead = in.read(buf)) >= 0) {
            counter++;
            moduleSet.append(new String(buf));
        }

        String[] blocks = moduleSet.split("#");
        System.out.println("Items: " + blocks.length);

    } catch (java.io.IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    return moduleList;
}
```

I tried with UTF-16 since strings are encoded in java in UTF-16, But it only makes the output worst.
Your suggestions will be appreciated...
Thanks

Comment: Never take pictures of source code and post them. Either copy + paste the source code into your question or take the time to type it up.

Comment: Problem may be located at position (242, 137)

Comment: @Jeffrey If at all possible, I would go with copy/paste.  If that were not possible because I was 'on the Kindle' or some such, I'd probably delay asking a question until I got back to the desktop development machine.  Too many errors creep in when (re) typing code.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I would also use copy + paste, but if the code was from a textbook the only option would be to retype it. At first I didn't notice the scroll bar on the side of the OP's image, so I didn't know that the code was from his IDE.

Comment: @Anuruddha You might want to look at [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) to see how to format your code correctly.

Comment: Previously I tried ctrl+K twice, that was the issue, I did it now, Thanks 
@Jeffrey

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would rip out the code where you convert your list contents to and from a string, and replace it with [ObjectOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html):

```
FileOutputStream out1 = new FileOutputStream(fileOut);
CipherOutputStream out2 = new CipherOutputStream(out1, encryptCipher);
ObjectOutputStream out3 = new ObjectOutputStream(out2);
out3.writeObject(moduleList);
```

Then, to read back:

```
FileInputStream in1 = new FileInputStream(fileIn);
CipherInputStream in2 = new CipherInputStream(in1, decryptCipher);
ObjectInputStream in3 = new ObjectInputStream(in2);
moduleList = (Set<String>)in3.readObject()
```

Comment: Yes it worked. By using your way, It doesn't need to traverse through each of the string in the list and sending. So i don't need to consider about encoding stuff at all. I can send it as a object and read it easily. it reduces significant amount of lines of codes. Thanks